# Enable two-step verification for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, support, login, user-accounts, authentication

I have two-step verification (via Google Authenticator) enabled for almost all of my accounts on the Internet. I somehow feel safe with that.

I have enabled two-step verification for almost all my accounts since I have read these news:

- [Australian government tells citizens to turn off two-factor authentication](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/12/australian-government-tells-citizens-to-turn-off-two-factor-authentication/)

I want hate remembering passwords, allow me to use 12345 (just kidding) everywhere and let two-step authentication take care of security for me. I wish to enable two-step authentication for all my Stack Exchange sites. How would I do that?

I Googled, but I couldn't find a way to enable it. So, may be it's a feature request (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: *Australian government tells citizens to turn off two-factor authentication* Wait what? Then what's the big deal with two-factor verification? I doubt this would be implemented on SE's part for a while - but if you log in via Google, then two-factor works like that

Comment: @Zizouz212 seems to be purely about 2fa for the government site only?  http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/12/australian-government-tells-citizens-to-turn-off-two-factor-authentication/  Still seems like really bad advice.

Answer (score 5):

> I wish to enable 2-step auth for all my stack exchange sites. How would I do that?

Use your Google account as your OpenID provider.  Setup 2FA in Google.

Or use whatever other OpenID provider you like that supports 2FA.

Comment: I don't have OpenID. I am using SE via Google plus. Do I need to create one?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan your Google account is your OpenID provider then.