# Log in using MFA?

Tags: feature-request, login, authentication

Is there a way to add [2FA or MFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) to my existing Stack Exchange login, or I do have to add a GitHub, Google, etc. login?

I tried searching the help and looking around the settings, but I couldn't see anything that mentioned 2FA or MFA.

Comment: Related: *[Two-factor authentication for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/two-factor-authentication-for-stack-exchange)* (2014)

Comment: Dupe, not just related. It's the same request.

Comment: *"[There isn't and won't be 2FA in SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304270/is-an-account-merge-a-valid-work-around-to-have-two-factor-authentication-in-my#comment989022_304270)"* (2017)

Comment: *"[Enable two-step verification for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274109/enable-two-step-verification-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)"* (2016)

Comment: *"[2FA for Stack Exchange universal login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318807/)"* (2018) and *"[Why not add optional simple TOTP 2FA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355251/)"* (2020). From the 2018 one: *"At this time, not really. The system hasn't actually changed all that much since that discussion, and pretty much all the same points and discussions stand. Most users aren't all that interested in having us implement this, so it will likely remain in the back seat to focus on more important things."*